# How to display content in xml format after xml parsing in grails?

Tags: grails, xml-formatting

I have a sample.xml which looks like this

`<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <Employee>
     <Name>ABC</Name> 
     <EmpId>100011</EmpId> 
     <Occupation>Programmer</Occupation> 
     <Company>XYZ</Company> 
     </Employee>`
`
 and the code to parse it is

```
def display = {
        def parser = new XmlParser()
        def doc = parser.parse("grails-app/conf/sample.xml")
        def map =  [data: doc]
        render (view:'/myxml',model:map) }
```

When I run this app I get the output as shown on myxml.gsp

`Employee[attributes={}; value=[Name[attributes={}; value=[ABC]], EmpId[attributes={}; 
value=[100011]], Occupation[attributes={}; value=[Programmer]],Company[attributes={}; 
value=[XYZ]]]]`

Is there any way I can get it in the format as shown

```
<Employee>
<Name>ABC</Name>
<EmpId><100011</EmpId>
<Occupation>Programmer</Occupation>
<Company>XYZ</Company>
</Employee>
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jjczopek is correct that `render doc as XML` is a good approach. If you want more control over things, or if your response is really HTML that includes an XML section, then you could use code like this:

```
def display = {
    def doc = new XmlParser().parse("grails-app/conf/sample.xml")
    def writer = new StringWriter()
    def nodePrinter = new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(writer))
    nodePrinter.preserveWhitespace = true
    nodePrinter.print doc

    render view: '/myxml', model: [xmlstring: writer.toString()]
}
```

and then in myxml.gsp you could display the XML with

```
<pre>
${xmlstring.encodeAsHTML()}
</pre>
```

Comment: Hey is there any way I can display only some tags of the xml doc? For ex: only name and occupation?

Answer (score 0):

If you read this file as normal text file , it should work. I am not sure of XML formatting though.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation has some exaples on rendering response as XML (http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/render.html). I never used it yet, but maybe something like:

```
import grails.converters.*

...

render doc as XML
```